# How can I read printer's data from a COM port?

Tags: printing, serial-port

I would like to use an usb to com adapter to sniff data sent from computer 1 that should arrive to a printer.

I'd connect computer 2 in the place of the printer so I'd have classic com port on computer 1 side and usb port on computer 2 side.

I can program using python (pyserial should be ok to read the data) and bash.

Which kind of tools should I use to turn the sniffed data into human readable text?

Or, maybe, is it simply possible to emulate a printer on computer 2 and turn directly data into text or pdf or anything readable?

Comment: So Ubuntu hardware related questions are off topic? Is this even an hardware question? Disagreed: see my answer.

Comment: Good one! Upvoted! (close vote retracted, dumb comments deleted!)  **;-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a very easy solution to read serial data with Python and PySerial on Ubuntu, here's the script:

```
# simply change COM9 with /dev/ttyS0 or the COM port you need to use
import serial
ser = serial.Serial("COM9", 9600)

while True:
   line = ser.readline()
   print line
```

I can read data from the input and now I can build a parser using python-escpos to turn it into readable text